# how openvpn and psiphon set proxy on android without root

Tags: android, proxy

I'm thinking of how this open source applications set proxy on android devices without root !
I'm trying to do something like that but no success. anyone know something about this ?

[OpenVpn](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.openvpn.openvpn&hl=en)

[Psiphon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.psiphon3)